# InvalidArgumentException Driver "ORM" is unsupported for this extension

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I don't know why show  this error "[InvalidArgumentException] Driver "ORM" is unsupported for this extension" after Sylius Assortment Bundle installation with this documentation http://sylius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusAssortmentBundle.html

After adding  these line In config.yml shows me error:

```
sylius_assortment:
    driver: ORM
    classes:
        model:
            product: Application\Bundle\AssortmentBundle\Entity\Product
```

Please any one suggest me What i am doing wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver name has changed to `doctrine/orm` instead of just `ORM`. The documentation is out dated. I have fixed it and added a pull request. It should get updated soon.

Answer (score 0):

With YAML (the config format) you must preserve the indenting

so indent the body of sylius_assortment with spaces:

```
sylius_assortment:
    driver: ORM
    classes:
        model:
            product: Application\Bundle\AssortmentBundle\Entity\Product
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this is the problem, I have taken this from the [official documentation](http://sylius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusAssortmentBundle.html#container-configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.I just add this code.Then it worked.

```
sylius_assortment:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        model:
            product: Application\Bundle\AssortmentBundle\Entity\Product
```